# How to find the height of a rectangle given its area and the difference between the base and the height?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, problem-solving

The rectangular base is $4.50 \text{ cm}$ shorter than the height and the rectangle has a surface area of $135 \text{ cm}$. Solve the rectangle height with an equation. I know and feel that this is pretty easy, but don't know where I am making a mistake.

So far I have tried

$(x-4.5)(x+4.5) = 135$ and $x^2 = 135$.

Comment: i ment to put x^2

Comment: If the base is shorter than the height call x the base length in cm. Then x+4.5 is going to be he height. And that other equation with $x^2$ is unnecessary

Comment: Change your title.  Yours is vague and irrelevant and will never help anyone finding this question... even someone who has the exact same question.

Comment: You are given product and difference of sides $x,y.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up two equations. We know that the base $x$ is $4.50 \text{ cm}$ shorter then the height $y$. Hence,

$$y=x+4.50 \text{ cm}.$$

The surface area $A$ is given by

$$A=xy=135 \text{ cm}^2.$$

Plugging $y=x+4.50 \text{ cm}$ into the equation for the surface area we obtain:

$$135\text{ cm}^2=x(x+4.50\text{ cm}) \implies x^2+4.5x-135 =0.$$

Now, solve with the quadratic formula to obtain $x$ in $\text{cm}$. Can you do this?

Comment: Oh, thank you for the help. I can solve it now, and also know what i were doing wrong!  ~~